# ADO connection to an open excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I have to following code copying data to different sheets in my main workbook from 12 different workbooks, every thing works great when the 12 workbooks are closed, but when one of them is open I get an error "the connection for viewing your linked Microsoft excel worksheet was lost" anyway to slove that or a connection can be made only to closed workbooks?

```
Sub callstuff()

Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies1.xlsm", "sheet2", "Helper1")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies2.xlsm", "sheet3", "Helper2")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies3.xlsm", "sheet4", "Helper3")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies4.xlsm", "sheet5", "Helper4")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies5.xlsm", "sheet6", "Helper5")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies6.xlsm", "sheet7", "Helper6")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies7.xlsm", "sheet8", "Helper7")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies8.xlsm", "sheet9", "Helper8")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies8.xlsm", "sheet10", "Helper9")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies8.xlsm", "sheet11", "Helper10")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies8.xlsm", "sheet12", "Helper11")
'Call GetDataFromClosedFile("Movies8.xlsm", "sheet13", "Helper12")
End Sub


Option Explicit

Sub GetDataFromClosedFile(WorkBookName As String, SheetName As String, TableName As String)
  
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim path As String

    path = "C:\Users\dima\OneDrive - ort braude college of engineering\Desktop\New folder (5)\" 'constant
    
    Worksheets(SheetName).Range("j4").CurrentRegion.Clear
    
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    
    cn.ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & path & WorkBookName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';"
        
    cn.Mode = adModeRead
    cn.Open
    
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    rs.Source = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] "
        
        
    rs.Open
    
    Worksheets(SheetName).Range("j4").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
     rs.Close
    cn.Close
    
 Dim rngTable As Range
  
    Set rngTable = Worksheets(SheetName).Range("j4").CurrentRegion
    Worksheets(SheetName).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTable, , xlNo).Name = TableName
  
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Was the workbook opened by another user ?

Comment: Yes the workbook is opened by a different user

Comment: What do you want the code to do when it can't connect ?

Comment: Transfer data from the workbook to the main workbook